Capacitor Charging with HV Pulses
I have some queries regarding capacitor charging using inductively generated HV pulses, in contrast to with regular DC. First, to check my understanding, I will recount the situation with non-pulsed DC.
If the energy supplied by the battery = then the capacitor, will always(?) receive and store 1/2 = 1/22 due to resistive, inductive and radiative losses.
So with a known value of capacitor being charged from a voltage Vmin to Vmax, as seen on a scope trace, one can calculate the energy stored and compare it to what was delivered by the battery and, at best, this will be 50%. In practice, it will likely be less due to other losses.
If the capacitor is then discharged, whatever energy was stored will again incur resistive losses, (possibly up to 50%?) such that, over a complete cycle of charging and discharging, perhaps only 25% of the original energy supplied by the battery is available for whatever the discharge energy might be used for.
Looking now at the situation with HV pulses, of the sort produced from the field collapse of a coil (flyback pulses), then the situation may be quite different and I am seeking to understand how charging takes place and, more importantly, the losses incurred during the charging and discharging stages.
With reference to the diagram below, the capacitor is made up of 4 ∗ 15 80 low ESR caps connected in parallel and with a combined measured value of 53.

The MOSFET Drain output pulses have a peak voltage of 1.7, a FWHM of 20 and a PRF of 50 and, on the face of it, the time-averaged voltage across the capacitor is zero since after the pulse rise time to a peak voltage it returns again to zero before the next pulse. However, practical measurements show a very real and rapid rise in capacitor voltage using such pulses, so clearly the pulses are resulting in a positive charge and voltage differential across the capacitor plates.
What I presume is happening is that with each HV pulse the capacitor starts to charge a little and, when the pulse voltage returns to zero, the capacitor is unable to discharge due to the presence of the top diode and the VDSwitch. As such the capacitor charges in small discrete steps in a staircase fashion and this is what appears as the ‘fuzzy’ charging curve on the 'capacitor voltage’ insert.
Assuming this is basically correct, of more interest is what losses are incurred in the charging and discharging stages and whether they are larger or smaller than with regular DC?
The reason for the interest is for my research into non-linear and ‘far from equilibrium’ effects of these voltage transients on batteries and capacitors. If the losses are such that, in a complete charge and discharge cycle, I am going to see more or less than approximately 25% of the battery input energy, then that is very significant.
Sorry for the long post but it’s important that I give a clear picture of the setup and context.

Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

This circuit doesn't look very practical/effective. But you might look into load dump or surge generator networks as far as testing nonlinear effects goes.

No I haven’t used LTSpiceIV on it. It may look impractical but it is the main setup for delivering pulses to secondary cells as part of the research study. Using the capacitor is for comparative purposes.

Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/828127/2451

You have drawn a boost converter.
Even if the high voltage output from your inductors is in the kV range when unloaded, when connected to the capacitors, the voltage will be clamped to whatever the capacitor voltage is.
Clamping the voltage to this low value will mean the inductor current decays slowly, and throughout that decay they are delivering charge to the capacitors. This is how a boost converter can approach 100% energy efficiency, if there are no resistances in the circuit to dissipate energy.
In fact this boost converter circuit is the ideal way to charge capacitors, when the output voltage is higher than the input voltage.

I hear you. So with a boost converter one gets around the typical resistive and inductive losses whereby 50% is not wasted in the fields generated?

Does this mean that by lowering the VMax of the capacitor when charging down towards the nominal battery voltage then the efficiency will be optimal?


If the energy supplied by the battery = then the capacitor, will
always(?) receive and store 1/2 = 1/22 due to resistive,
inductive and radiative losses.

There is one mistake in what you say above. Series inductance in the feed to the capacitor can save the day and allow virtually the full energy to be imparted to the capacitor. Of course you also need a diode and that diode will lose a bit of energy so, it's not 100% energy transfer but it's much higher than 50% (if you didn't have sufficient inductance).
This is how boost converters work. This is what your diagram is.

So I am hearing. It wasn’t planned to be that but the schematic shows the key elements of the circuit. What I am hearing is that by using this type of cap charging then the usual losses are avoided. I have not heard of a boost converter normally using HV pulses. I have an off the shelf one elsewhere in my main system for raising the battery voltage a few volts when required.

@JulianPerry you can't overcome resistive losses but, you can prevent the peak current from theoretically being infinite amps when you apply a voltage source directly to a discharged capacitor. The inductor smooths the flow of energy from input voltage source to capacitor.

Ok, so assuming we could transfer the battery energy with 100% efficiency, then what about the losses with the high current discharge to the battery? Is that subject to 50% losses? If so then it makes sense for me to stick with a calculation based on the scope waveform, but is 1/2 C(dV^2) still relevant to calculate the energy transferred to the capacitor? If not how can I calculate it?

The discharge into the load battery is subject to 50% losses. Maybe if you explained why you wanted such a strange way of dumping energy into the battery I might see an alternative approach.

I would have to explain the whole research project which I won’t do here. As has been noted by others I first posted this question in Physics but was told it should be posted in electrical, hence the ‘cross post’. If you like I can give you this link to my recent publication and you can write via the email in my ORCID profile which can be accessed with the small green icon at the end of my name near the top of page 1. https://doi.org/10.33140/JEEE.03.04.05

The use of a capacitor serves to provide a comparison for the effect of the pulses with secondary cells (as in the paper) and where the dump here is just a means to remove the capacitor energy so another scope trace can be achieved to provide a series. Alternatively, the cap’s energy can be actually measured through a discharge with a computerised battery analyser but I would need to know the precise losses to know what was in the cap to start with. Hence the second part of the question.
